# Reactjs Fetch throwing Parsing JSON giving “unexpected token " error

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch-api, jsonresponse

I am making a fetch api call. When I make that call with json data directly, I get the response but when I make api call with relevant needed headers I get errors like **unexpected toke o** or SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

I tried to use **JSON.parse(response)** and then tried **json.response()** but nothing seems to work.

```
export const trackingInfoFetchData= url => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch(trackingInfoIsLoading(true));
        fetch(url, headers:{headers})
       .then((response) => {
           if (!response.ok) {
               throw Error(response.statusText);
           }
           dispatch(trackingInfoIsLoading(false));
           return response;
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((items) =>{
            dispatch(trackingInfoFetchDataSuccess(items))
          })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(trackingInfoHasErrored(true));
        const errMsg = 'Unknown Error Occurred: '.concat(error.message);
        dispatch(displayError(errMsg));
    })
  };
```

Comment: Post the raw text of the JSON data that you are getting from the API call.

Comment: What’s the HTTP response code of the response? 405? If the `url` you’re making the request to is at a different origin than where your frontend code is running (cross-origin request), then the headers you added to the request are probably triggering your browser to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. And the server is probably responding to that with some kind of error — a 4xx or 5xx error — and so the content you’re getting back isn’t JSON but is instead some HTML error page.

Comment: On the server side I am getting HTTP 200.

Comment: com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter$Adapter finish
INFO: 4 * Server out-bound response
4 < 200
4 < Content-Type: application/json
[{"customerPk":"2juuxvk9f7zpxysapmqh3w2sh4hwhe4r","trackingId":"Cancel: Recreated Account","comments":"test","byRep":"bsoo","externalData":null,"externalRef1":null,"externalRef2":null,"externalRef3":null,"created":"2017-12-14T18:29:23.086Z","updated":"2017-12-14T18:29:23.086Z"},{"customerPk":"2juu4hwhe4r","trackingId":"ExternalPartner: Stream","comments":"For Unit test","byRep":"Reference","externalData":"{\"data\":[{\"FreeSponsorID\":\"DPeng\"}]

Comment: On the server I get HTTP 200 ok and if I console.log it before response.json(), I get the response on console but after that it hits the parsing error like  like unexpected toke o or SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

Comment: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) this is one of the error

Comment: When  debug and reach at respponse.json(), after that the response is lost